# Is [tips-and-tricks] a meta tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, burninate-request

While looking at [the revision history for a particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21133/revisions), I noticed that the [tips-and-tricks](/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks) tag was removed in revision 3.

This made me curious, so I looked at other questions that still have that tag:

- [Explain this duplicate line removing, order retaining, one-line awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842118/explain-this-duplicate-line-removing-order-retaining-one-line-awk-command)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104929/replace-two-word-each-one-with-other-one
- [IP Cam to Gtalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302548/ip-cam-to-gtalk)

Ok, so there's a whole bunch of questions out there that have nothing to do with "tips and tricks".  Let's see if we can find some questions that the tag DOES apply to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818303/hidden-php-debugging-techniques-with-xdebug [closed]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891886/what-are-your-favourite-zsh-tips-tricks-and-features [closed]
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065472/any-good-git-tips-and-lesser-known-features [closed]

I'm noticing a pattern here....

I think it's time to squash [tips-and-tricks](/questions/tagged/tips-and-tricks):

- For questions that are on-topic, it's a meta tag.
- For questions where it's not a meta tag, the question is off-topic.

Comment: So are [tag:tricks] and [tag:hacks]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meta tag or not, the wiki entry for it says `DO NOT USE` since April 30, 2012:

> DO NOT USE - Removed as part of [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Comment: Per the [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128315/164291) in the tag wiki:  "Don't just remove the tag; review the question and fix anything else you can find in the process."  In other words, looks like this tag isn't getting burninated any time soon.

Comment: @todofixthis Your link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly this tag survived but only had 6 questions left this morning.

And then there were none.